# Destroy and Set jquery datepicker on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, destroy

I am using Jquery with ASP.NET MVC and create one page that has some fields to enter the data and have some condition based functionality.

Like I have option to choose Job Order Date in selection equals to, not equals to , today, tomorrow , etc...

[image]

So I have to set the right side textbox as datepicker or some time only textbox based on selection of the dropdownlist value.

If from first till greater than equals to I want textbox as datepicker and on selection of the last two options i.e. in last x days and in next x days I want to only textbox not datepicker I mean I want to destroy the datepicker.

[image]

I have done following code but not getting the result.

```
function checkselection(obj) {
            if ($("#ddl_" + obj + " :selected").text() == "in last x days" || $("#ddl_" + obj + " :selected").text() == "in next x days") {
                removedatepicker(obj);
                $("#txt_" + obj).attr("disabled", false);
            }
            else {
                setdatepicker(obj);
                $("#txt_" + obj).attr("disabled", false);
            }
        }

    function setdatepicker(id) {
                $('#' + id).datepicker({
                    autoclose: true
                });
            }

            function removedatepicker(id){
                $('#' + id).datepicker("remove");
            }
```

obj is the id of the textbox.